# Class Design and Collections

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

If I have a class defined as:

```
public class Car{
    public int doors {get;set}
    public int wheels {get;set}
    public string make {get;set}
    public string model {get;set}

    public Car(){}
}
```

And I want to create a collection of this class.  In the past I have understand it was acceptable to create a collection class:

```
public class CarCollection{};
```

That would return a collection of Cars.

With Generic List now I understand that we should not be creating collection classes, but instead creating generic list of the object inheriting some collection type.

My question is where should this code go, and what definition should the method have?  For example should I just add a public method to my car class:

```
public List<Car> GetAllCars()
{
    ...
}
```

If so, it seems weird to instantiate a Car Class to get a collection of cars, but I know declaring it as a shared class isn't the right option either.  How should we be designing our collections of classes, and where should we be including them?

Comment: Define `List<Car>` where you have to use it, for example you can define it in your `Main` method *(for console app)*, and if you have to share it , you can share that `List`

Comment: I need to populate the list of Cars from the database, so defining it where it's used didn't seem like the right answer.  Should I create a separate Data Access Class that defines List<Car> and populates it?

Comment: Yes you can do that, return a `List<Car>` from your method responsible for accessing DB and getting records.

Answer (score 1):

It all depend how you want to use the collection of the cars. But in the scenario you mentioned in the comment, I would suggest looking into repository pattern, which would be an intermediate layer between the business logic and database.

So you would have you `Car` class as a model, and a repository e.g.: `CarRepository`. This repository would have a method for returning the list of all your cars. All the logic for populating this list would be in that class, and it would not pollute other places of the application and increase maintainability of the code.

```
   public class CarRepository {
    public List<Car> GetAllCars() {        
        // read data from DB and return list        
    }

    public Car GetSingle(int carId) {
        // here you just return single car
    }
   }
```

This is just to give you an idea how this might be done. Going further you can extend this concept introducing interfaces for easy testing and swapping implementations for the repository. You could then have single interface, with multiple implementations - one for reading from DB and e.g. second one for reading from XML file.

There is a lot of reading material regarding that on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks @jjczopek.  I've been looking for some good reading material.  What search terms should I be using to find this material.  I haven't been able to locate any quality material.

Comment: Try that one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/631668/Learning-MVC-Part-Repository-Pattern-in-MVC-App it refers to MVC, however the concept is not only limited to MVC and web apps, but can be used everywhere.